# How to search the span element through XPath within google-chrome-devtools

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to search for the HTML below:

```
<span data-login="true" class="button-tab-links--gray hide-for-medium-only"> Olá, Visitante</span>
```

using

```
//span[@class="button-tab-links--gray hide-for-medium-only"]
```

at Google Chrome to search element but doesn't work. What do I need to change?

[image: Chrome dev tool screenshot of element]

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to find is the string "Ola Visitante", you could try search for that instead using:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Ola Visitante')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per these three (3) information within the image:

[image: hidden_elements]

The desired element is within an **`<iframe>`**

### Solution

To search the *XPath* for the `<span>` element through [[image]google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) you have to *select* the desired `<iframe>` clicking on the element where currently **top** is selected.